# ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript Popups

Tags: popup, arcgis-js-api

I have ArcGIS for javascript 4.24 and the following code where i want to display a popup if the user clicks outside of a polygon.

```
view.on("click", function (evt) {
            view.hitTest(evt).then((response) => {
                // check if an existing marker is selected
                if (response.results.length  && response.results[0].graphic.popupTemplate != null) {
                    // do nothing as the popup is set to automatically open on click event
                } else {
                   
                        let newPoint = view.toMap({
                            x: evt.x,
                            y: evt.y
                        });
                        let newMarker = new Graphic(newPoint, markerSymbol);
                        positionLayer.removeAll();

                        if (!geometryEngine.contains(boundaryPolygon, newPoint)) {
                  
                           view.openPopup({
                             title: "some title",
                             content: "This location is outside the boundary",
                             location: newPoint  
                           });
        
                           
                
                        } else {
                            // Custom data handling
                            
                        }
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

However the openPopup function is only available in ArcGIS v 4.27

How do I open a popup in ArcGIS v 4.24? I tried the following and it doesn't work either:

```
view.popup.open({
                             title: "some title",
                             content: "This location is outside the boundary",
                             location: newPoint  
                           });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to disable popup auto open by changing the popup property `autoOpenEnabled` to `false`.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>
        Code Popup Open 4.24
    </title>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.24/"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
            "esri/Graphic"
        ], (Map, MapView, GraphicsLayer, Graphic) => {
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "satellite"
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                zoom: 5,
                center: [-101.94981250000075, 41.20977753557709]
            });
            
            const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

            const graphic = new Graphic({
                geometry: {
                    type: "point",
                    x: -101.94981250000075,
                    y: 41.20977753557709
                },
                symbol: {
                    type: "picture-marker",
                    url: "https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/satellites-3d/live/satellite.png",
                    width: 64,
                    height: 64
                }
            });
            
            view.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false; // <-- deactivate popup auto open

            graphicsLayer.add(graphic);
            map.add(graphicsLayer);
            view.on("click", function (evt) {
                view.hitTest(evt).then((response) => {
                    if (response.results.length === 0) {
                        view.popup.open({
                            title: "Miss",
                            content: "You need to click the satellite!.",
                            location: evt.mapPoint
                        });
                    } else {
                        view.popup.feature = graphic;
                        view.popup.open({
                            title: "On Target",
                            content: "You click the satellite!.",
                            location: evt.mapPoint
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Important**: The action needed to disable popup auto open change from the popup (like mention above) to the view (property `popupEnabled`) in version **4.27** (to be fair it is bit different the logic also).